# In what kind of context people would use "papoose" to refer to child?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I read the following passage in an article of *The Atlantic*:

> In films of the period documenting orphan care, you see nurses like assembly-line workers swaddling newborns out of a seemingly endless supply; with muscled arms and casual indifference, they sling each one onto a square of cloth, expertly knot it into a tidy package, and stick it at the end of a row of silent, worried-looking **papooses**.

I looked it up and it seems to mean baby carrier most of the time but in this context I’m sure it refers to a baby instead of a baby carrier. So I wonder in what kind of context people would refer to a child as a papoose. Like to sound more literary?

Comment: This term was *somewhat* still used when I was growing up in the 80s, but I haven’t heard it used, even ironically, for decades. Now, this is NYC, and I can’t say it’s not used regularly *somewhere*, but I don’t see it arise in any American or otherwise English-speaking media, either.

Comment: Could the term not here refer to the assemblage of the two, that is, to a tightly wrapped baby?

Comment: @BrianDonovan That was generally my impression of the word when I used to hear it, yes.

Comment: It's archaic.  Was not too uncommon 50 years ago, but I haven't seen the word in 10-20 years.  I'm guessing the writer purposely used the anachronism, to reflect the period of the movie.

Comment: FWIW, Travis Scott used the word in "Sicko Mode": *"Was off the Remy, had a Papoose"*. Based on the [Genius annotations](https://genius.com/15121028), it's primarily a reference to two other rappers, but also an allusion to his own kid.

Comment: Since its origins are Native American, my guess is that the term's usage has decreased along with a growing emphasis on avoiding the potential for linguistic cultural offenses. LIke @DanBron, I haven't heard it used in years.

Answer (score 13):

It can mean both and in the text, the author seems be referring to both carrier and occupant as a collective.

[From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papoose)]:

> **Papoose**: (from the Algonquian papoose, meaning "child") is an American English loanword whose present meaning is "a Native American
> child" (regardless of tribe) or, even more generally, any child,
> usually used as a term of endearment, often in the context of the
> child's mother. The word came originally from the Narragansett tribe.

...

> A Papoose carrier: Cradle boards and other child carriers used by
> Native Americans are known by various names. In the United States and
> the United Kingdom, the term "papoose" is sometimes used to refer to a
> child carrier. Some tribal members consider this usage offensive.